# What ports do I need to open for firewall for Aeron Cluster to work?

Tags: aeron

I have an Aeron Cluster working at AWS nodes and I also have a cluster client locally (ie my box) and I try to talk to it... In terms of security, I only opened the cluster Ingress UDP port to allow my box to go through. When I try to connect, I can see the Cluster's AeronStat show:

50:                   56 - Cluster timed out client count - clusterId=0

I'm not sure what's happening behind the scene but I'm curious if there are more ports I need to open for heartbeat or some other background traffic to go through?

Note that if I run the cluster locally and everything is localhost, it works fine.

Comment: Can you post an example config that you are using that is not working for you?  In testing I've just opened all of the ports, but been specific about which nodes the clients are running on.  You also have make sure that you can UDP traffic back out from the cluster node to the client.  This will be on the egress channel port (potentially a system allocated ephemeral port).

Answer (score 0):

Previously i have experience the same issues. However if your box is in your home/laptop/office maybe internet providers (ISP) block UDP connection or might be in the router settings.

What I'm doing is to do full remote development using Visual Studio Code Remote SSH to edge nodes then develop there.